# ReadPersonalContacts Permission for RingCentral API

Tags: permissions, user-permissions, ringcentral

I'm trying to access user contacts via the RingCentral API using password authentication of a Super Admin. I've given the app Contacts and ReadContacts permissions, but when I try to access the contacts list of a specific extension, I get this error:

```
"errorCode" : "CMN-408",
  "message" : "[ReadPersonalContacts] permission required",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "CMN-408",
    "message" : "[ReadPersonalContacts] permission required",
    "permissionName" : "ReadPersonalContacts"
  } ],
  "permissionName" : "ReadPersonalContacts"
```

That specific permission isn't an option in the API Developer settings panel. Any idea how to give my app that permission?

Answer (score 1):

Ben,

This error is related to user permissions rather than app permissions.
The reason you're getting this error is that you are trying to access the personal contacts of the extension user. Only the extension users can access their own personal contacts.

We have created a ticket to fix the error message and show a more appropriate message.

Thanks,
Pawan Venugopal

Comment: You're saying a super admin can't access the contacts for individual users? Why not?

Comment: can you try out this api and provide the response. https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-explorer/latest/index.html#/!/Roles_and_Permissions/loadUserPermission

Comment: We have 2 types of contacts. Company Contacts and Personal Contacts. Company contacts are all extensions within the organizations which can be accessed by super admin. Personal contacts are contacts added by an individual user (user of an organization) which can only be accessed by the user who added the contact. You could also perform the permission check by invoking the API: https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/authz-profile/check?permissionId=ReadPersonalContacts

Comment: If I'm a Super Admin, and paying for the User's account, then I don't understand why I'm not allowed to access their personal contacts. I can do it through the RingCentral dashboard, so why can't I do it through the API?